# CSS Media Queries and body margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media

(Skip to bold text for actual question)

I'm using Bootstrap to make a Bootstrap WYSIWYG editor for the browser.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        Content gets edited here
    </div>
    <div class="sidepanel left"></div>
    <div class="sidepanel right"></div>
</body>
```

The side panels each take up 200px, and are positioned as fixed. The body margin is such that the container won't overlap.

```
body {
    margin: 0 200px;
}
```

I need to ride off Bootstrap's built in responsive capabilities. I want to be able to adjust the body margin in order to be able to preview the site on other screen sizes—I should be able to increase the margin to make the view smaller.

The media queries in bootstrap deal with columns and hiding content on different screens.

**However, the body margin isn't being taken into account with the media queries, and instead gives the width of the full window. I need the media queries to measure the effective window width (window width - body margins). What would be the best approach to do this?**

Edit. I've used an iframe to do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add margins to the `container-fluid` div, and solve this problem completely?

Comment: Why don't you just resize your browser window to test smaller screen sizes?

Comment: Adjusting the margins of container fluid didn't help. The effective size of the content div is 806px, and it thinks it's large (>1200px).
There are panels beside the content editor. Adjusting the browser window will make them in the way.

Comment: Isn't that the point of media queries? To re-arrange elements on smaller screens so that they aren't in the way?

Comment: Yes. But I have to put the sidebars in so the site is functional. They have to be there, and they reduce the viewing size, but this change is not reflected in the media query.